# Can't find the "Stop debugging" button in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio

as the name suggests, I've recently started using Visual Studio 2022, and while I've enjoyed it so far, it seems like my "Stop debugging" button has just... vanished from the toolbar. The usual options such as Start debugging, Apply code changes or Reload are all there, but not the Stop debugging one.
As anyone else encountered this issue, and if so, how do I add that button back in the toolbar?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Can you please provide the screenshot of your problem?

Comment: Is Visual Studio fullscreen? By default, the "Stop debugging" button is not present on the **Standard** toolbar, but on the **Debug** toolbar. So either 1) The Debug toolbar is hidden, check by right-clicking the empty toolbar space and see if **Debug** is checked 2) The **Stop Debugging** button is hidden. Check by clicking the overflow arrow of the Debug toolbar and see if the third option is checked

Comment: You find the toolbar designer under "Tools/Customize" or use the drop down button besides every toolbar on the toolbar menu. If thats all to complicated you might try the "panic" button. On "Tools/Import and Export Settings.." is a "Reset all Settings" option.

Comment: With your current interpretation please refer to
Pieterjan's suggestion. If your problem cannot be solved, please provide relevant screenshots of the problem.

Answer (score 10):

Look for the small arrow (showing downwards) on the top-right:

[image]

[image]

[image]

After that you can arrange it accordingly by pressing "Move Down" or "Move Up":
[image]